# prepared statement mysqli not returning rows

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have some php code with a prepared statement. It is called via Ajax in javascript. I am sure there is an account called mark (no caps) in the accounts table, but when I call this with $_POST['query'] set to m it finds $stmt->num_rows===0 to be true. No errors can be seen, it just doesn't work! As you can tell, it is echoing content into a table. I tried this query in phpMyAdmin: SELECT username FROM accounts WHERE username LIKE '%m%' and it worked fine. I created this code to search a mysql database for usernames. In case your wondering, $conn is a valid mysqli object defined in the include file.

```
<?php
require_once('./include.php');
$stmt=$conn->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare('SELECT username FROM accounts WHERE username LIKE ?');
$compquery='%'.$_POST['query'].'%';
$stmt->bind_param('s',$compquery);
$stmt->execute();
echo '<tr><td>';
if($stmt->num_rows!==0){
    $stmt->bind_result($name);
    while($stmt->fetch()){
        echo "$name</td></tr><tr><td>";
    }
   echo '</td></tr>';
}
else
    echo 'No Results Found</td></tr>';
```

Comment: Have you used `mysqli_stmt::store_result()` [Doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php)?

Comment: Do you need quotes around the ? in the prepared statement?

Comment: already did error checking, just took it out of the question.

Comment: no quote around ? in prepared statement. it is added automatically with bind_param argument s.

Comment: Thank you @Passerby. That completely makes this work. I'll wait 5 minutes if you want to post the answer, but if you don't I'll just post the answer and credit you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Extending from comment:

You have to use [`mysql_stmt::store_result()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php) before you can use `mysqli_stmt::num_rows`:

```
$stmt=$conn->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare('SELECT username FROM accounts WHERE username LIKE ?');
$compquery='%'.$_POST['query'].'%';
$stmt->bind_param('s',$compquery);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
```